# different encoding problem when using knit and running chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am reading csv files that has the character ý  which seems to cause a problem prompting the message:
Error in type.convert.default(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,  :
invalid multibyte string at ''

I have managed to overcome this by adding the function: Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C").

Yet, this does not work when I press "knit". Then I get the same error message as above.

I have managed to overcome this by adding an fileEncoding "latin1" for each csv file.

But now when I don't knit, just run the chunk, it doesn't work!
I get an eroor "invalid input found on input connection- filename- EOF within quoted string".

So I need to keep adding and deleting the fileEncoding...

Can anyone help?

Comment: `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")`  affects the current session.  `knitr` usually runs in a separate session.  You can make it run in the current one by running `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")`.  It might also work to put the `Sys.setlocale()` setting into the RMarkdown document so it applies to the rest of the document.